# Tick text/variable labels not wrapping in d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, observablehq

I'm trying apply line wrapping to long variable labels along the x-axis in a d3 bar chart. Here's an my chart in an Observable notebook: https://observablehq.com/@unfpamaldives/figure4

I've attempted to apply a solution [from this block](https://bl.ocks.org/guypursey/f47d8cd11a8ff24854305505dbbd8c07), consisting essentially of the following:

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em")
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word)
      tspan.text(line.join(" "))
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop()
        tspan.text(line.join(" "))
        line = [word]
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", `${++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy}em`).text(word)
      }
    }
  })
}  

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick text")
      .call(wrap, x.bandwidth())
```

What it looks like:
[image]

What I'm trying to achieve:
[image]
I've also tried moving the `wrap` function elsewhere, earlier and later in the code, as well as tried moving the following lines

```
.selectAll(".tick text")
  .call(wrap, x.bandwidth())
```

to work from somewhere in this block of code, like so:

```
xAxis = g => g
.attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .style("font-family", "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Cn")
  .style("font-size", "9px")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))
.selectAll(".tick text")
  .call(wrap, x.bandwidth())
```

But [this too](https://observablehq.com/@unfpamaldives/figure4/2) (attempting to adapt [Bostock's solution](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321)) does not work. (I've gotten text wrapping to work in other d3 visualizations before, for what it's worth.) Can anyone demonstrate a working solution based on a fork of [my Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@unfpamaldives/figure4)?

Comment: tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() always returns "0"

Answer (score 2):

I successfully applied a text wrapping technique for the x-axis bar/variable labels featured in [this example](https://observablehq.com/@gerardofurtado/wildlife-support-vs-submarines) from [Gerardo Furtado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5768908/gerardo-furtado). It entails the following code:

```
  svg.append("g")
      .call(yAxis);

  const axis = svg.append("g")
      .call(xAxis);  

  setTimeout(()=>{
  axis.selectAll(".tick text")
      .style("font-family", "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Cn")
      .style("font-size", "9px")
    .call(wrap, x.bandwidth());
  }, 0);
```

Here's the [working solution](https://observablehq.com/@unfpamaldives/figure4/3).

Comment: hi I am giving fixed with on the bar item with this line `Math.min.apply(null, [x.bandwidth(), 40])` and again the bar item not aligning  to the `x-axis` tick . would you give me some ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `wrap` is not working, already hinted in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2820991/mohammed-raja), is due to how Observable's cells run. According to Mike Bostock, Observable (and D3) creator,

> [this problem] occurs commonly in Observable because the standard pattern is to implement cells as “pure” functions where you create detached elements and return them, and then they are inserted into the DOM; so within a cell, you should nearly always be working with detached elements. ([source](https://talk.observablehq.com/t/getbbox/1222/2))

So, when you call `tspan.node().getComputedTextLength()` there is nothing in the DOM yet, and therefore it returns zero.

My solution, as you [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60421837/5768908), is simply using a `setTimeout` with 0 milliseconds, so the elements will be in the DOM when you need to measure them. One could argue that this is hacky, and it is indeed! By the way, Bostock's solution, which is along these lines...

```
const foo = html`<html structure here>`;
document.body.appendChild(foo);
//get the length of foo...
foo.remove();
```

... is just as hacky, possibly even more.

Comment: I'm having this issue, but I'm also using transition on the x-axis, so this solution is not perfect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122871/wrapping-long-labels-with-axis-transition-in-d3-js-v4.

Comment: @eudoxyz yes, I agree, I don't know why this question was linked to yours, because your problem is fundamentally different.

Comment: Do you have any pointers for solving the problem I'm having, please?